# How to configure Kibana docker-compose to put ElasticSearch containers in same network

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, docker-network

I have this docker-compose.yml config:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.3.1
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: kibana.interos.io
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://elasticsearch.example.org
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.3.1
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx2512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.3.1
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx2512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  esdata02:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

how to can I tell Kibana to use the same docker network as the elasticsearch containers? I assume I have to add

```
 networks:
      - esnet
```

to the kibana container, anything else I need to do? What is the best practice here?

Comment: What happens if you add the `networks:` section you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is right. The kibana service needs to look like this:

```
kibana:
  image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.3.1
  networks:
    - esnet
  environment:
    SERVER_NAME: kibana.interos.io
    ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://elasticsearch.example.org
```